# Scalatra GZipSupport when using FutureSupport

Tags: scala, jetty, gzip, scalatra

I have a ScalatraServlet as follows:

```
class MyServlet extends ScalatraServlet with FutureSupport with GZipSupport with JacksonJsonSupport {
..
}
```

When running, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
```

I've also tried adding a jetty filter as follows in my ScalatraBootstrap:

```
val gzip = context.addFilter("gzip-responses", classOf[NicsGzipFilter])
gzip.setInitParameter("mimeTypes", "text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/json,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml")
gzip.setInitParameter("minGzipSize", "1") // TODO for testing only. Remove before committing
gzip.addMappingForUrlPatterns(java.util.EnumSet.allOf(classOf[DispatcherType]), true, "/*")
gzip.setAsyncSupported(true) // not sure if this is required?
```

In this case, I get responses, but they are not gzipped (although the jetty filter definitely runs because it adds a vary encoding header).

I seem to be getting the same error as reported here: [ScalatraServlet with AkkaSupport with GZipSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218851/scalatraservlet-with-akkasupport-with-gzipsupport) . So it doesn't look like the bug was fixed.

Another suggestion for why it's not working was made here: https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/issues/247#issuecomment-12219667 . The suggestion is that Scalatra is calling outputting using a writer and output stream within the same response, which isn't allowed.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chatted to rossabaker on IRC and after submitting a sample application which replicated the problem he identified the issue and came up with a fix: https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/pull/316 .

It turns out the FutureSupport trait was not respecting the response wrapper generated by the GZipFilter.